# Closed-Form solution for $D_n$

Tags: linear-algebra

I let $D_n$ be the determinant of the $N \times n$ tridiagonal matrix $A$,
where
$$A_{i,j} = \left[\begin{array}{ccccc} 1&-1&...&...&0 \\ 1&1&-1&...&0 \\
0&1&1&-1&... \\ ...&...&...&...&... \\ 0&...&...&1&1 \end{array}\right].$$

I want to find a closed-form solution for $D_n$. I was recommended that
I prove a particular recursion related to $D_n$ and then solve for $D_n$ using
a generating function technique, but I am having some difficulty finding this
recursion. I conjecture that
$D_n = D_{n-1} + D_{n-2},$ in a similar extent of the Fibonacci series. However,
I am having difficult proving this.

I start by performing the cofactor calculation method on the first row,
so
$$D_n = det(A_{(n-1) \times (n-1)})- det(A \ \text{without first row and column
2}),$$

but I am having difficulty proving my recursion from this statement.
Any suggestions on this problem?

Comment: In the second term in your equation for $D_n$, expand along the first column.

Comment: Also, the operator between the two terms should be $+$, since $a_{12} = -1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a specific case of a general formula for determinants of matrices which lend themselves to recursive formulas.

For a write up on this check out https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL13/Janjic/janjic33.pdf